Undesired space between form children elements
here, if i set the text input width to 80% and the button width to 20%, the button gets pushed to the next line, as if the width of the two elements combined exceeded the inputContainer width. i dont get why this happens, but im assuming its something with the parent form element, because i can see that there is an undesired space between the input field and the button. if i set a width of 80% to the input field and 18.9% to the button, they both fit on the same line, but with a bit of space between each other. i believe thats why the button gets pushed down if i increase its width to 20%. whats happening here?
i tried to set all the elements to box-sizing border-box and remove all paddings and margins from every single html elements to make sure the width is fine... but thats not happening.


* {
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.container {
  border: 2px solid gray;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  position: relative;
}

.container h1 {
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

.messageBoxReceived {
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  height: 10%;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.username {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray
}

.username p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.receivedMessageContent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.receivedMessageContent p {
  margin: 0;
}

.username2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray
}

.username2 p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.messagesContainer {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 10%;
  height: 75%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.inputContainer {
  height: 15%;
  position: relative;
  top: 10%;
}

.inputContainer form {
  height: 100%;
}

.inputContainer input[type="text"] {
  height: 100%;
  width: 80%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.inputContainer button[type="submit"] {
  height: 100%;
  width: 18.9%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="messagesContainer">
    <div class="messageBoxReceived">
      <div class="username">
        <p>usuarioMandandoMensagem</p>
      </div>
      <div class="receivedMessageContent">
        <p>what is good my brothers im trying some stuff here so im typing random shit to see how this behaves you know lol thats how it goes trynna type some more just a bit more you know lol maybe a bit bit bit more</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="inputContainer">
    <form action="/sendMessage" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="" id="">
      <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Teste de Chat</h1>
  </div>
</div>



